# Requisição form-data, com okHttp3

Tags: java, api, java-ee, rest

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição onde tenho que passar alguns parametros no Body, conforme a imagem.

[image: Exemplo de como deve ser feito]

Exemplo:
Key: file[], Value: "xml", Content-Type: application/xml
Key: query, Value: {"boxe/File": false}, Content-Type: application/xml.

Estou recebendo erro de Bad Request, creio que meu codigo não eteja certo.
Segue como esta sendo feito

```
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file[]", xml, RequestBody.create(null, "application/xml"))
            .addFormDataPart("query", "{\"boxe/File\": false}", RequestBody.create(null, "application/xml"))
            .build();
    


    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(endPoint).addHeader("x-integration-key", integrationKey)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
            .post(requestBody).build();

   Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver, a ordem dos parametros estava incorretas...

Segue a forma correta

```
  RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("file[]","", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/xml"), xml))
            .addFormDataPart("query", "", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), boxFileJson))
            .build();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).